# Appcelerator Installation Issue - SyntaxError

Tags: installation, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

I am trying to install Titanium Appcelerator on `Windows 7` `64-bit` PC.

I am following the tutorial [Appcelerator Fresh Install](https://titaniumsolution.blogspot.in/2016/12/fresh-installation-appcelerator-studio.html?showComment=1492259344334#c183728894173724903),

At step 3, i.e., on running command `appc use latest`, The admin command prompt is throwing error `Unexpected end of input`, Please refer the image [image: Installation error]
I have cross checked if 32-bit JDK is installed, as mentioned in Documentation

> The 32-bit version of the JDK is required regardless of whether Titanium is running on a 32-bit or 64-bit Windows system.

`java -d64 -version`

This gave an output

which states that i have installed 32-bit JDK, [Check if 32-bitJDK is installed](https://coderanch.com/t/521212/java/check-jdk-bit-version-bit)

Please help me installing Appcelerator.

Comment: Problem is with the node.js version, minimum required node is 4.6 and higher

Answer (score 0):

I guess its the node version. Check if it works with node 4.6.2. See some more details at: https://github.com/m1ga/titanium_with_atom#windows